# bitstream details of wav, mp3 file

Tags: file, multimedia, bitstream

I would like to know about the meaning of each byte in a wav / mp3 files.
But find nth from google...anyone knows where i can find such information?
(Infact I would like to know all types of multimedia files in the bitstream level)

Answer (score 0):

MP3 files are divided into frames, each begins with a sequence of `FRAMESYNC` bits so hardware can find the beginning of each frame. More [here](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html).

Some info about WAV is [here.](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html)